# connecting to TCP/IP modbus slave with an IP address

Tags: tcp, localhost, modbus

I have a TCP/IP Modbus slave running on my desktop. I can happily connect a TCP/IP Modbus master to it through 127.0.0.1, port 502 on the same desktop.

But I want to connect to the slave by a master on another machine on the network.
The IP address of my machine is 192.168.3.58.

Whether the master is on my desktop or on another machine, I cannot connect to the slave using an IP address of 192.168.3.58, port 502.
I can ping 192.168.3.58 from my desktop (as I would hope!) and from other machines on the network.

Please suggest what my mistake is!
Thanks

Comment: Are you doing this over a work network which may have firewalls in place that might block odd port traffic?

Comment: Thanks, Nanomurf... that turned out to be the answer. I had to configure` Windoes firewall.

Comment: Voting to close this ancient issue as firewall is the obvious thing to check first RTFM.